# How can I present the significance of two statistical tests in one table?

Tags: statistics, tables

I am working on my first independent publication and am unsure how to report the significances of two statistical tests in one table.
My professor has recommended that I should perform two statistical significance tests for robustness and present them in my article.
So far I have only done the t-test.
(If the value is significant according to the t-test, asterisks are added indicating the significance)
But I should add the significance of the Wilcoxon test as well.
The problem is that my tables with the t-test are already big enough and I can't expand them any more.

What can I do to also report the significance of the second test in the same table?
Should I perhaps write the values in **bold** if they are also significant according to the second test?
Or does anyone have a completely different idea?
Adding columns to the table or creating a new table is out of the question.
Here you can see an example of a table:
[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Those stars (three on all but two entries) use lots of real estate and are very distracting. Footnotes for just those two would help whatever else you do.

Without the stars you might be able to report the second set of results this way:

```
xx.x (yy.z)
```

with the caption explaining the parenthetical numbers.

You can also format to make better column width choices.

Please align the columns on the decimal points.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a different symbol.**

You're reporting your t-test p-values using asterisks, just use crosses or daggers or any other symbol to denote the Wilcoxon p-value. Alternatively, just list the p-value itself in the table - the way it's formatted, it would actually occupy *less space* than the asterisks. I'd also recommend cleaning up the table a bit - there's not really any reason to include the single asterisk in the legend since it's not used anywhere in the table (although you might want to keep it if some Wilcoxon p-values are between 0.1 and 0.05). You can also tighten the spacing between the asterisks, as they currently draw more focus than the values themselves, and take up a lot of space.